# How to change href of a Widget menu item link?

Tags: php, filters

I assume that using a filter would be the best way to do this, but I am not so familiar with php code so I require someones masterful input please!

Here is the widgets menu:
[image: widget menu]

This widget comes with the theme that I am using, which does not allow me to manually edit the links. I would like to overwrite the destination of these menu items with a custom link.

If it is at all useful, the widget is called: Thim-login, and the list of items are contained within this class: `.widget.widget_thim-login`

Here is also some sample html of the widget:

`<div class="widget widget_thim-login"><a href="LINK" class="user-name"><span class="author"></span><img alt="" src="GRAVATAR-LINK" srcset="GRAVATAR-LINK" class="avatar avatar-45 photo" height="45" width="45"></a><ul class="user-info"><li class="menu-item menu-item-courses"><a href="LINK">My Courses</a></li></ul></div>`

Many thanks!
- D

EDIT:
Perhaps I can adapt this code to also over-ride the links? ...

```
    add_filter( 'thim_header_user_dropdown_content', 'handle_menu_dropdown_profile' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'handle_menu_dropdown_profile' ) ) {
    function handle_menu_dropdown_profile( $dropdown_content_args ) {
        if ( isset( $dropdown_content_args['become_a_teacher'] ) ) {
            /*$dropdown_content_args = array(
                'become_a_teacher' => esc_html__( 'Become An Instructor', 'course-builder' ),
                'courses'          => esc_html__( 'My Courses', 'course-builder' ),
                'orders'           => esc_html__( 'My Orders', 'course-builder' ),
                'certificates'     => esc_html__( 'My Certificates', 'course-builder' ),
                'settings'         => esc_html__( 'Edit Profile', 'course-builder' ),
            );*/
            $dropdown_content_args['settings'] = esc_attr__( 'My Profile', 'course-builder' );

            return $dropdown_content_args;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to wordpress.stackexchange. What you're asking might be too specific for someone to give a good explanation to without knowing more about the exact way things are setup on the site. Have a look at the [how to ask section](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what I mean. You may be able to edit this by visiting `Appearance >> Menus` but if not, could you please provide some samples of the menu code &/or the name of the theme & plugins you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is a widget menu (not the main nav menu). I believe that the widget comes as part of the "Thimpress Course Builder" theme, and the destination links go to users "Learnpress" Profile (another plugin). I've updated the original post with some sample HTML. Perhaps this will help?

Comment: If it's a menu widget there should be a corresponding menu on the appearance >> menus page at `wp-admin/nav-menus.php` you can make as many nav-menus as you want there & use them for however many menu-widgets you need or output them in locations already specified by the theme.

Comment: This looks like a hard-coded widget, rather than an actual nav menu. You would likely need to contact the theme author to determine whether it's possible to change the links, or else build your own widget to replace it.

Comment: WebElaine is correct. Unfortunately they themselves can't seem to answer this, hence why I came here :) But I understand if it's a tough one. Worst case, I could use a Redirection plugin I guess!

Comment: I've just added some php code to the OP which enables me to change the text of the widgets. Perhaps I could adapt this to also overwrite the links?